# Changing color of text on click HTML

Tags: html

I'm currently learning HTML. I have to do an exercice where a text must change back and forth from red to green.
The code I have is below but doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.red { color : #FF0000 }
.green {color : #00FF00; }
<script type='text/javascript'>
function f(){
  value=1
  if (value == 1) {
    document.getElementById("txt").className = "green";
    value = 0 
  }
  else if (value == 0) {
    document.getElementById("txt").className="red"  
    value = 1
  }
}
</script>
<p id='i1'>This is <em> special </em> <span id="txt" class='red'>text</span>.</p>
<p id="click"  onclick='f();'>Click to change the colour of text</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set any value. Check directly `txt` class.

```
function f(){
  var txt = document.getElementById("txt");

  if (txt.className == 'green') {
   txt.className = "red";
  }
  else {
    txt.className = "green";
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/33526/

Comment: What if element has class `has-padding color-red red button`?

Comment: Requirement suggests only one class. If it has more class, then we can set some value and check as you did

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `value` is always re-set to 1.

I suggest using [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to set current state of your element.

```js
function f() {
  var el = document.getElementById('txt');
  
  if (el.dataset.val == 1) {
    el.className = "green";
    el.dataset.val = 0;
  } else if (el.dataset.val == 0) {
    el.className = "red"
    el.dataset.val = 1;
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: #FF0000
}
.green {
  color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<p id='i1'>This is <em> special </em>  <span id="txt" class='red' data-val="1">text</span>.</p>
<p id="click" onclick='f();'>Click to change the colour of text</p>
```

---

**jQuery**

```js
function f() {
  $('#txt').toggleClass('red green');
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.green {
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='i1'>This is <em> special </em>  <span id="txt" class='red'>text</span>.</p>
<p id="click" onclick='f();'>Click to change the colour of text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### CHANGES

- Used `addEventListener()` instead of attribute event handler. Now presentation is completely separated from code.
- Hinged the color states upon the method `classList()` since everything is centered around classes. More styles can extend the function's functionality easily.
- Used event delegation by adding the event handling on the parent element (`#content`) and then singling out the origin of the event trigger (`e.target` is the element clicked) Event delegation will save us tons of time, work, and memory, instead of writing an event handler on each element, you write only one.

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content');

content.addEventListener('click', f);

function f(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('red')) {
    tgt.classList.remove('red');
    tgt.classList.add('green');
  } else {
    tgt.classList.add('red');
    tgt.classList.remove('green');
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.red {
  color: #FF0000
}
.green {
  color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<section id='content'>
  <p class='red'>This is <em> special </em> text.</p>
  <p class='green'>Click to <b>change</b> the colour of text</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is that you run your code in the wrong order, your basic algorithm is this:

onclick -> 
f() start ->  
set value to 1 -> 
check if value is 1 
(true){set color to green} 
   (false) {set color to red}

then if the user clicks again, that same algorithm will run again.

this is what you should do:

```js
    var value = true;
    function f() {
        var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
        if(value) {
            document.getElementById("txt").className = "green";
            value = false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("txt").className = "red";
          value = true;
        }
    }
```

```css
.red { color : #FF0000 }
.green {color : #00FF00; }
```

```html
<p id='i1'>This is <em> special </em> <span id="txt" class='red'>text</span>.</p>
<p id="click" onclick="f()">Click to change the colour of text</p>
```

this way, you set `value` as true (1 is basically true, and 0 false), then wait for the user to click, set the text to green, changing the `value` to false, then if the user clicks again, you won't reset `value`, instead, it will still be false and the text will be set to red and set `value` back to true.