# Javascript polygon color check

Tags: javascript

So I'm a complete beginner if it's about polygons.
I have a polygon with `id="a"` and when it's clicked, a function named `changecolor()` is getting called. I set the default color to green, and I want it to change to another green when it's clicked, now when its clicked again I want it to check what color it is and based on that it changes the color back or not, here's the function `changecolor()`:

```
function changecolor(){
    if(a.style.fill === '#73e600') {
        a.style.fill = 'green';
    } else {
        a.style.fill = '#73e600';
    }
}
```

This code seems to work if I do it with `'green'` instead of `'#73e600'`, so my question is how do I make it to work with the hexadecimal color code as well?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909834/changing-color-of-text-on-click-html/40910053

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not to do with setting the colour, but with your conditional.

The conditional `if(a.style.fill === '#73e600')` will never return true, because `a.style.fill` returns a value like `'rgb(115, 230, 0)'`.

The simplest workaround would be to change your conditional to `if(a.style.fill === 'rgb(115, 230, 0)')` and run it again.

However, you might run into browsers behaving slightly differently, so you are probably better off using a css class for each colour, and switching class on click instead of changing the fill property directly. There will be no problem checking the class name.